# Document not found issue in Sitecore 10 in every sitecore panel

Tags: habitat

```
ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
```

I am facing the above error in logs while accessing `Sitecore 10.0`, we just did a fresh installation and integrated `Habitat solution`. Apart from this, the Automation Engine Service is failing to start as well.

[image]

Comment: This issue seems related to your XConnect website or certificate issue, please verify if xconnect is up and running and also you used right thumbprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by commenting the following line in the site config

```
setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false"
```

I believe this setting was creating this problem in `Sitecore 10.0` Now it is working fine. Firstly I tried everything with certificates and permissions and all that stuff but that didn't work for me, this resolved the issue.